# top command doesn't show me the full path of COMMAND

Tags: shell, cron, top-command

I wrote this shell script named example.sh on Linux.

```
#!/bin/sh

TOPLOG=/tmp/top.log
date +%H:%M:%S >> ${TOPLOG}
top -b -c -n 1 |head -n 8 |tail -n 2 >> ${TOPLOG}
echo >> ${TOPLOG}
```

When I run it with the command "sh /tmp/example.sh", texts in top.log is like

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                
17980 cybereas  20   0 1478m  73m  18m S  2.0  0.5   1360:59 /opt/cybereason/sensor/bin/cybereason-sensor
```

However, when I run this script with this crontab

```
*/1 * * * * sh /tmp/example.sh
```

texts in top.log is shown like

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                
17980 cybereas  20   0 1478m  73m  18m S  2.0  0.5   1360:59 /opt/cybereason/sen
```

The output of "COMMAND" is omitted when it is a little long.

Is there any solution for this?
I appretiate for any idea.
Thank you.

Comment: read te documentation? `man top` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When not printing to a regular file, and not a terminal (`>> "$TOPLOG"`), `top` is truncating output to the standard terminal width of 80 columns.

If your `top` has the `-w` switch, add `-w 512` for a larger maximum width.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Unfortunately, my `top` doesn't have `-w` option, but I used `COLUMNS=150 top -c` instead.